# YiiBooster $form->checkboxListGroup values preselect

Tags: yii-booster

Can someone help me in `YiiBooster` checkboxListGroup. I'm trying to preselect items in

```
$form->checkboxListGroup(
        $modelPermissions,
        'ID',
        array(
            'widgetOptions' => array(

                'data' => array(
                            'a'=>'1111',
                            'b'=>'2222',
                            'c'=>'3333',
                        ),
            ),
        )
    );
```

But with no success.
Can anybody help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify in model field the values that you want to be default checked.
Try this:

```
$modelPermissions->id=array('a','b');
```